# How can pass model metadata through tag helper to a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, tag-helpers

For customization of input, I add a tag helper and a partial view. My problem is model validation attribute, id, the name does not generate as I expected. I Wrote the code in asp.net core 5.

For example when I don't use the tag helper as following code

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Title"></label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input asp-for="Title"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Title"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Generated Html for input(Title) is following code, and as you see data-val attributes, id, the name is OK

```
<input type="text" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="Title is required" id="Title" name="Title" />
```

But when I use CustomTagHelper as following

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "custom")]
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IHtmlHelper html;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression DataModel { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public CustomTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        html = htmlHelper;
    }
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        (html as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        var content = await html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_Custom.cshtml", DataModel);
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
    }
}
```

_Custom.cshtml

```
@model ModelExpression

<input asp-for="Model" />
<i class="fas fa-football"></i>
```

Usage of CustomTagHelper in the View

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div custom="" asp-for="Title"></div>
    <span asp-validation-for="Title"></span>
</div>
```

Generated Html when I have used CustomTagHelper

```
<input type="text" id="Model" name="Model" class="valid" aria-invalid="false">
<i class="fas fa-football"></i>
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: I think your `_Custom.cshtml` should have dynamic model, otherwise it's hard to have a model for it so that `asp-for` can extract the property (which is also dynamic) you want. Imagine that you prepare a dynamic model (even an anonymous object is fine) having the property `Title` (this can be dynamic, in this case its name is `Title`). You pass that model to the `_Custom.cshtml` and there you also know beforehand that a `Title` property should be available, so you can set `asp-for="Title"` there.

Comment: @Hopeless I don't want to specify the property name in _Custom.cshtml,

Comment: if you want the `Title` info to be cascaded once from the outermost scope, the code in `_Custom.cshtml` cannot use `asp-for` because that will capture the property (of the model) you pass in there. If that property is dynamic, it will not work. You need to write another custom tag helper (replacing `asp-for`) of your own to deal with dynamic property.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but you may try this (in `_Custom.cshtml`): `<input asp-for="Model" name="@Model.Name"/>`. It's obviously a kind of manual task however.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is model validation attribute, id, the name does not generate as I expected.

That is because it is Model in your `asp-for` tag helper,the generated html is correct.For your scenario,you need follow what @Hopeless said to custom another tag helper to replace `asp-for`,or you could abandon partial view and change to use StringWriter to write html in backend.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "custom")]
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression DataModel { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public CustomTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var textArea = _generator.GenerateTextBox(ViewContext,
                                DataModel.ModelExplorer,
                                DataModel.Name,
                                DataModel.Model,
                                null,
                                null);

            textArea.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);

            writer.Write(@"<i class=""fas fa - football""></i>");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, generated Html is <input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name">, I want Name be Title

Comment: Ohhhh,my mistake.Check my updated answer.

Comment: I want to use a partial view for Html because my main project needs a complex Html artifact, I use a simple one  in question for brevity